# Select values that SQL JOIN fails on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently, to figure out what value a join is failing on in SQL I use the following method

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACC.Name
     ,ACC.Area
     ,CASE
          WHEN A.Area IS NULL AND N.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name and Area do not match'
          WHEN A.Area IS NULL 
               THEN 'Area does not match'
          WHEN N.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name is null'
          ELSE 
               'Yes'
          END as IsTopAccount
 FROM Test.dbo.Accounts ACC
 LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.TopAccounts A ON A.Area = ACC.Area
 LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.TopAccounts N ON N.Name = ACC.Name
```

In the above, an account must be joined to the `TopAccounts` table on both Area and Name. The two joins are necessary for me to test for each condition in the case statement.

Is it possible to test for each condition in the case statement more efficiently, perhaps with one `LEFT JOIN` instead of two seperate `LEFT JOIN`'s?

See this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eea35/3)

Comment: Your current query doesn't make sense to me: if there is no record `A` with `A.Area = ACC.Area`, or no record `N` with `N.Name = ACC.Name`, then isn't it 100% guaranteed that there will be no record `P` with `P.Area = ACC.Area AND P.Name = ACC.Name`? (Are you ever actually seeing `Area does not match` or `Name is null` in your result-set?) So it seems like your query is equivalent to what you'd get if you removed the second and third `WHEN` expressions and the second and third `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: @ruakh thanks, I had not noticed that, please see the updated query and sql fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, I think a single *`FULL OUTER JOIN`* which gives not matching records as *`null`* from both tables, would also give the results. [Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ff82/6)

```
SELECT A.Name ,A.Area
      ,CASE
          WHEN TA.Area IS NULL AND TA.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name and Area do not match'
          WHEN A.Area IS NULL 
               THEN 'Area does not match'
          WHEN TA.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name is null'
          ELSE 
               'Yes'
          END as IsTopAccount
 FROM A  FULL OUTER JOIN  TA 
      ON TA.Area = A.Area AND TA.Name = A.Name
```

You can change the CASE to check null from both tables as required. Here are some good [visual examples about joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

As per comment, Same results with a single `LEFT JOIN` [Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c71e/20)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Name ,A.Area,
          CASE WHEN TA.Area IS NULL AND TA.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name and Area do not match'
          WHEN TA.Area <> A.Area 
               THEN 'Area does not match'
          WHEN TA.Name <> A.Name
               THEN 'Name is does not match'
          ELSE 'Yes' END IsTopAccount
FROM A LEFT JOIN  TA 
      ON A.Area = TA.Area OR A.Name = TA.Name
ORDER BY A.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think my original question was unclear, please see the update.

Comment: @stevebot, it is still not very clear. Can you show some sample data and expected results? It would be easy that way I think.

Comment: I updated your SQL fiddle example to match my expected behavior. Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eea35/3

Comment: @stevebot: can get the same results with a single `Left Join` and `<>` operator in `case`. Updated my answer and you could use Order by for easy comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this would work:

```
SELECT ACC.Name
     ,ACC.Area
     ,CASE
          WHEN T.Area IS NULL AND T.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Not matching at all'
          WHEN T.Area != ACC.Area
               THEN 'Matching for name only'
          WHEN T.Name != ACC.Name
               THEN 'Matching for area only'
          ELSE 
               'Yes'
          END as IsTopAccount
 FROM A ACC
         LEFT JOIN TA T ON T.Area = ACC.Area 
                                        OR T.Name = ACC.Name
```

Comment: I was just about to post almost this same answer too. But "OR T.Area = ACC.Name" seems to be unnecessary and in fact not correct. You should just be able to remove that, right?

Comment: Also, disagree with the edit you just made testing T.id. Don't think that's actually necessary, and is also make assumptions about the OP's table structure.

Comment: gosh, being systematic also has its counterpart

Comment: the t.id is necessary, otherwise how would you know there's even anything matching? It depends how you interpret the SO's need though, let's see the comments. I am going to clarify by modifying the returned strings

Comment: Change ur first When to : WHEN T.Area IS NULL AND T.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name and Area do not match'. This is because when both are not matching then T.Id will also be NULL ...

Comment: When both area and Name are not matching T.ID will be null, hence it will always hit the first when and would never go to second when. In my opinion just remove when with NO as result i.e. remove:  WHEN T.id IS NULL 
               THEN 'No'

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe do it with two:

```
SELECT ACC.Name
     ,ACC.Area
     ,CASE
          WHEN A.Area IS NULL AND N.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name and Area do not match'
          WHEN A.Area IS NULL 
               THEN 'Area does not match'
          WHEN N.Name IS NULL
               THEN 'Name is null'
          ELSE 
               'Yes'
          END as IsTopAccount
 FROM Test.dbo.Accounts ACC
 LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.TopAccounts A ON A.Area = ACC.Area
 LEFT JOIN Test.dbo.TopAccounts N ON N.Name = ACC.Name
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. You can do it with two, and doing it with three (my previous query) is incorrect. I have updated the question now, and I am hoping to get the number of joins down to one.